# GPT Passbacks without document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I'm trying to use the passback functionality of the gpts without booking it directly in dfp. Unluckily until now without success. If I'm booking this snippet

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
  googletag.pubads().definePassback('/ID/AD_Unit', [728, 90]).setTargeting('key', ['value']).display();
</script>
```

everything is working properly. Then I tried following snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.url.de/to/gpt_ad.js"></script>
```

gpt_ad.js contains the snippet above with document.write wrapped. That is working too. Now I tried it with document.createElement instead of document.write. The code snippet is:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.type = 'text/javascript';
tag.src = 'http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var code = 'googletag.pubads().definePassback(\'/ID/AD_UNIT\', [728, 90]).display();';
tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));

var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, node);
```

Inserting worked but there are no ads showing. I'm a bit clueless. I also receive following error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.  > pubads_impl_75.js:195

Comment: The problem is that DFP works asynchronously, so you CAN'T use `document.write`, but you can check an option inside DFP to force synchronization.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it but in the second variante I don't use _document.write_ but **document.createElement** instead. And the document.write variante is working

Comment: But the code inside `http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js` is using a `document.write`

Comment: Although it's not a problem when I'm using document.write respectively I don't get a warning/error. And it's using the lib the same way as I can see.